# How to nonvivificate in Perl

Tags: perl, autovivification

Let's say I have a Perl script that does:

```
my $hash = {};
$hash->{'a'} = {aa => 'b'};
$hash->{'b'} = undef;

for (qw(a b c)) {
    if(defined $hash->{$_}->{aa})
    {
        say "defined $_";
    }
    else
    {
        say "undef $_";
    }
}
print Dumper $hash;
```

But my output autocreates 'c', which I don't want.

```
defined a
undef b
undef c
$VAR1 = {
      'c' => {},
      'a' => {
               'aa' => 'b'
             },
      'b' => {}
    };
```

Also my distribution does not allow me to disable autovivification. is there a way to make a subroutine that checks each level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple function that checks each level for existence and stops without autovivifying intermediate levels. The prototype isn't necessary; it makes it act (sort of) like the built-in `defined`. This version only works for nested hashes (except blessed hashes and overloaded objects that look like hashes).

```
sub noVivDefined(+@) {
    my ($x, @keys) = @_;
    foreach my $k (@keys) {
        return unless ref $x eq 'HASH';
        return unless exists $x->{$k};
        $x = $x->{$k};
    }
    return defined $x;
}

my %h = (
    a => { b => 1 },
    b => { b => 0 },
    c => { b => undef },
    d => { c => 1 },
);


say noVivDefined %h, qw(a b);   # prints '1'
say noVivDefined %h, qw(a b c); # prints ''
say noVivDefined %h, qw(x y z); # prints ''
say noVivDefined %h, qw(b b);   # prints '1'
say noVivDefined %h, qw(c b);   # prints ''
say noVivDefined %h, qw(d b);   # prints ''
say noVivDefined \%h, qw(a b);  # prints '1'
```

Comment: Personnally, I'd return a reference to the element. That way, you don't need to dive a second time to work with the value you discovered was defined. `my $ref = dive \%h, @k; if ($ref && defined $$ref) { say $$ref; } else { say "[undef]" }`

Answer (score 11):

Call `no autovivification` in the desired scope:

```
for (qw(a b c)) {
    no autovivification;
    if(defined $hash->{$_}->{aa})
    {
        say "defined $_";
    }
    else
    {
        say "undef $_";
    }
}
```

If the `autovivification` pragma is not available, the usual idiom is to test for existence of the top level hash before you run a check at a deeper level:

```
if ($hash && $hash->{$_} && defined($hash->{$_}->{aa}) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: How would I do that programmatically? as in, if I called `noVivDefined($hash->{$_}->{aa};`

Comment: @EricFossum: You'd call the function as `noVivDefined($hashref, @keys)`. It would loop over the keys and do `defined` checks at each level.

Comment: @Eric Fossum, You mean it can't install [autovivification](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=autovivification&mode=all)? That would be weird.

Comment: `noVivDefined` already exists as [Data::Diver](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Diver)'s `Dive`.

Comment: LOL! Weird! There was no typo, but cpan can't find it using the normal URL I use. Anyway, updated the link.

Answer (score 3):

What is wrong with:

```
if (exists $hash->{$_} and defined $hash->{$_}->{aa})
```

Comment: That's not very programmatic... if I wanted to write everything out I'd just not use loops.

Comment: Adding **one** expression (~24 characters) to your entire example makes it "not pragmatic" and causes you to "write everything out" and "defeat the purpose of loops"? That is ridiculous hyperbole. Offer a real example that actually shows the problem then...